# Failed to undeploy WildFly 10 using Groovy script

Tags: shell, groovy, wildfly

I'm trying to undeploy an application on WildFly 10 using Groovy. For undeployment, I'm executing the following command through a Groovy script

```
'{Wildfly_home}/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --command="undeploy {earfile}"'.execute()
```

The command wasn't getting executed at all. So I captured error stream which gave me following message:

```
'***.ear"' is assumed to be a command(s) but the commands to execute have been specified by another argument: ["undeploy]
```

I tried by removing the double quotes as well but of no use.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Does your earfile have spaces in the path?

Comment: There are no spaces in the file path.

Comment: how successful command looks like when you run it from shell?

Comment: The command that we run from shell is {Wildfly_home}/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --command="undeploy {earfile}" . And it runs successfully

Comment: Are you sure you posted the exact Groovy line you use? If I execute `'{Wildfly_home}/bin/jboss-cli.bat -c --command=\\"undeploy foo.ear\\"'.execute().consumeProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)` I get the same error than you, if I execute `'{Wildfly_home}/bin/jboss-cli.bat -c --command="undeploy foo.ear"'.execute().consumeProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)` it correctly tells me that the deployment foo.ear is not found.

Comment: I executed the command for valid ear file. but I encountered the same error. The above command executes successfully when run through shell.

Comment: As I said, this is a quote-escaping issue. whether the deployment exists or not is not relevant as the commandline parser already freaks out in your case.

Comment: Quote escape didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Just a long shot: looking at the manual

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Command+Line+Interface?_sscc=t

I would suggest something like

```
'{Wildfly_home}/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --command=undeploy\ {earfile}'.execute()
```

or

```
'{Wildfly_home}/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c "--command=undeploy {earfile}"'.execute()
```

Please note that the idea is to have the interpreter to parse all the --command... as a single argument, maybe that way we can get the argument the way it is expecting it.

*Edited*

Maybe your problem is the way to execute the whole command line.  Tried to do something like this?

```
def arguments = [ '/bin/sh', '-c', '/wherever/it/is/jboss-cli.sh', '-c', '--command=undeploy /some/dir/your.ear' ]
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(executionChain);
builder.environment().putAll(envVars);// optional
builder.directory(baseDir); // optional
Process p = builder.start();
int ret = p.waitFor();
```

Maybe this way the interpreter will stop hurting you by separating the command argument.

Comment: I had tried the first suggestion from you, which gave me same error  message. I tried the second way but still got error as     '***.ear"' is assumed to be a command(s) but the commands to execute have been specified by another argument: [" --command=undeploy]

Comment: Editing the answer in order to put it the way it is recommended now in the Java manual.  It looks your problem is to beat the command line interpreter in order to get your arguments together,

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the issue. The edited command is as below

"{Wildfly_home}/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --command='undeploy {earfile}'".execute()

I swapped the single quotes with double quotes and vice versa.  And it worked for me. 
Thank you for the help.